# Memcache and Memcached not working on PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit

I have configured my PHP to have Memcache/Memcached installed and enabled.

Typing `php -m` shows me both extensions:

```
% php -m | grep memcache
memcache
memcached
```

With `php -i | grep memcache` I also have the two extensions loaded.

```
% php -i | grep memcache
memcache
memcache support => enabled
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.chunk_size => 32768 => 32768
memcache.compress_threshold => 20000 => 20000
memcache.default_port => 11211 => 11211
memcache.hash_function => crc32 => crc32
memcache.hash_strategy => consistent => consistent
memcache.lock_timeout => 15 => 15
memcache.max_failover_attempts => 20 => 20
memcache.prefix_host_key => Off => Off
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_subdomain => Off => Off
memcache.prefix_host_key_remove_www => On => On
memcache.prefix_static_key => no value => no value
memcache.protocol => ascii => ascii
memcache.redundancy => 1 => 1
memcache.session_prefix_host_key => Off => Off
memcache.session_prefix_host_key_remove_subdomain => Off => Off
memcache.session_prefix_host_key_remove_www => On => On
memcache.session_prefix_static_key => no value => no value
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2
memcache.session_save_path => no value => no value
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 1.0.18
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.default_binary_protocol => Off => Off
memcached.default_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.default_consistent_hash => Off => Off
memcached.serializer => igbinary => igbinary
memcached.sess_binary_protocol => On => On
memcached.sess_connect_timeout => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => On => On
memcached.sess_consistent_hash_type => ketama => ketama
memcached.sess_lock_expire => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_max_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_retries => 5 => 5
memcached.sess_lock_wait => not set => not set
memcached.sess_lock_wait_max => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_lock_wait_min => 150 => 150
memcached.sess_locking => On => On
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_persistent => Off => Off
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => Off => Off
memcached.sess_remove_failed_servers => Off => Off
memcached.sess_sasl_password => no value => no value
memcached.sess_sasl_username => no value => no value
memcached.sess_server_failure_limit => 0 => 0
memcached.store_retry_count => 2 => 2
Registered save handlers => files user memcached memcache
```

But even thought when running PHPUnit and trying to get Memcache / Memcached classes I receive a Class not found error.

The problem is that some tests rely on retrieving data from an API which is cached, so the tests fails without reason.

I installed both extensions correctly, made sure it's working on CLI.
When running `phpunit` it should work properly and the classes should be found.

Should I make any special setup for having these two extensions enabled on PHPUnit?

Comment: _"Should I make any special setup for having these two extensions enabled on PHPUnit?"_ - no, none that I can particularly imagine. phpunit runs with the default php configuration (CLI) from the binary invoking the test-runner. perhaps you want to run `php -f path/to/phpunit-runner -- ...`  to double-check you're using the right php config.  what does `command -v phpunit`  give? what does `file /full/path/to/phpunit` (`file $(command -v phpunit)`) give? And welcome to SO!

Comment: @hakre thanks for the quick answer! `php -f ~/.composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` doesn't work also. `command -v phpunit` returns `/Users/x/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit`. And `file $(command -v phpunit)` returns `/Users/x/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit: a /usr/bin/env php script text executable, ASCII text`

Comment: It's good practice to add additional infos to the question, [edit] it for that. from that info in the comment this should be just the `php` command from enviroment, which you've checked already with `php -i` etc. according your question. I'm a bit puzzled honestly, what is blocking the internal classes to load from those extensions. Are you using process isolation by chance in some of the tests?

Comment: Please provide the full error message in the question and the (fragment) of the code that is causing it so that the issue is better visible.